# How can I split string and integer when user input both the string and the integer in the same line in C++?

Tags: c++

I was doing Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps. I think I know how to solve the problem in C++. However I don’t know how can I split string and integer when user input both the string and the integer in the same line. They are separated by two spaces.

[image]

Comment: Read the entire line into a string the split it on the spaces?

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read each line, and `std::istringstream` to parse each line

Answer (score 2):

Just stream them from `std::cin` which uses space as a separator:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::string s;
    int a;
    std::cin >> s >> a;
    // process a and s
}
```

Comment: FYI, line breaks also count as ignorable whitespace by `operator>>`, which is why this code works.  However, know that this code is only reading the 1st 4 lines of input, it is not reading the remaining 3 lines.  So it does not satisfy the entire requirements of the assignment as documented

Comment: @RemyLebeau I actually needed help for that only. I know how to solve the problem. I just didn't know how to separate the string and integer when user input both in the same line.

Comment: You must validate the read as well `if (!(cin >> s >> a)) { /* handle error */ }`. Whenever you take input, any input, from a file, from the user (and especially from the user) you ***validate the read succeeds*** by **checking the return** (technically the input *stream-state* here.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> phoneBook;

    int n;
    std::string line;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream(line) >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::string name;
        int phoneNumber;
        std::istringstream(line) >> name >> phoneNumber;
        phoneBook.push_back(std::make_pair(name, phoneNumber));
    }

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(phoneBook.begin(), phoneBook.end(),
            [&](const std::pair<std::string, int> &entry){
                return (entry.first == line);
            }
        );
        if (iter != phoneBook.end())
            std::cout << iter->first << "=" << iter->second << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/MCtOFW)

On the other hand, if there are never any duplicate names in the phone book, consider using a `std::map` instead of a `std::vector`:

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> phoneBook;

    int n;
    std::string line;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream(line) >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::string name;
        int phoneNumber;
        std::istringstream(line) >> name >> phoneNumber;
        phoneBook[name] = phoneNumber;
    }

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        auto iter = phoneBook.find(line);
        if (iter != phoneBook.end())
            std::cout << iter->first << "=" << iter->second << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/BGEckJ)

Comment: Any reason for `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no particular reason

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the standard function, `scanf()` for taking input from `stdin` in `C`, since the input for phonebook entries, name & number, are space-separated.

So, use like the following:

```cpp
char name[<size>];
int num;
scanf("%s %d", &name, &num);
```